# Update URL after opening modal, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, modal-dialog

I am kinda new to react and I would like to change the url once the user has clicked to open a modal window. There's also some data coming with the modal that I would like to reflect in the url. E.g. "my.app/folders/project-name/"

I tried some solutions with react router but I do not seem to get it just right...

Here is the modal that I wish could update the URL once it's opened.

```
{modalOpen ? (
    <ProjectModal
      projectName={target[0].project_name}
      organization={target[0].organization}
      avatar={target[0].organization_avatar}
      client="xy"
      selectedImg={target[0].images[0]}
      gallery={target[0].images}
      onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)}
    />
  ) : null}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved Adam? I'm currently running in to the same issue and would love some insight on how you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this route mentioned in your Router. Something like this,

```
<Route path="parent" component="ParentComponent" />
<Route path="parent/modal" component="ParentComponent" />
```

Then you will have to use the history.push method while setting the variable to open the modal.

`history.push('/parent/modal');`

Hope my answer helps.

Checkout the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%E2%80%9Chistory%E2%80%9D%20and%20%22,in%20JavaScript%20in%20various%20environments.) for more info.